# Writing a script or program that "Traces" lines of an image

Tags: scripting, programming-languages, image-processing

I'd like to build a small application or script that will take an image as input and output the information for creating a graph (coordinates, vertices, edges, etc.). I'd like to be able to just drop blue dots on an image where a "vertex" would be and draw red lines along the paths to be edges. So I was wondering if anyone had any language/library suggestions for tracing along lines of an image? I realize I probably *could* do this with almost any language, but does anyone have suggested language for such a problem?

Comment: DO you mean draw at known points on the image, or find some feature in an image and return it's coordinates (to draw at) ?

Comment: The image would be already drawn on, to simplify finding coordinates and vertex points. Using the output I'll be creating a Graph data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step would be to extract edge information from the image using [Canny Edge Detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector).  Then, you would look for lines (curves, etc) within the edge information.  The [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) is useful for this task.  This will give you the *edges* you want for your graph.  By finding the intersections between the *edges*, you can find the *vertices*.

You're right in saying that this can be done in any language.  Just pick the one you're most comfortable with and Google around for the required libraries.  Personally, I use Python and OpenCV for this sort of stuff.

Finally, what you're asking for seems to be related to raster image [vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics).  You may want to Google around for that, as there are already technologies that perform that task.

Comment: This was extraordinarily helpful, thank you. I had it in my head *how* I'd go about doing it, but I knew there'd be some techniques that would help a lot. This is great.